# How is $ \sum_{x \in X(\mathbb{F}_q)} \dots $ a generalization of cardinality?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, harmonic-analysis

This quarter Maxim Kontsevich is offering a course on exponential integral.  There is not much in the way of notes, but is [one page](https://indico.math.cnrs.fr/getFile.py/access?resId=0&materialId=3&confId=694) with mysterious comments.

> Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $f \in \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a function.  Then  $(X,f)$ is a generalization of variety.
>   $$ \sum_{x \in X(\mathbb{F}_q)} e^{ \frac{2\pi i}{p}\mathrm{Tr}_{\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p} [f(x)]} $$
>   is generalization of the number of points.

Can someone explain how this generalizes cardinality?  Does the Gauss sum generalize the number of points of $\mathbb{F}_p$?

---

I know of a few notions of cardinality but I never figured out how to use them, so they are mostly novelty.

- [$q$-analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog) e.g. $[n]_q = 1 + q + \dots + q^{n-1}$ and [Gaussian binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}{k}_q$
  (Book by [Kac](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WB5O1W).)
- John Baez [The Mysteries of Counting: 
  Euler Characteristic versus Homotopy Cardinality](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/counting/)

Comment: Specialise to the case $f=0$.

Comment: @Terry well, ok. But one could come up with any number of functions that do that. In what sense is this a generalisation? What is it measuring? cf [groupoid cardinality](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/groupoid-cardinality/)

Comment: This notion obeys similar axioms to those in your link, if one generalises a bit further to trace weights of sheaves.  There are also a number of deeper properties that these statistics have in common with ordinary cardinality of varieties over finite fields, such as being attached to an L-function with a functional equation, and also obeying a Grothendieck-Lefschetz fixed point formula.  See e.g. https://blogs.ethz.ch/kowalski/2012/10/14/trace-functions-i/

Comment: [One should think of cardinality here as being like the operation of pushforward of a measure, specialised to the case where the target is a point.]

Comment: @DavidRoberts Well, you're just weighting each point with a value according to a certain function.  The same could be said of the trace of a f.d. representation being a generalization of counting conjugacy classes. What is interesting about these sums is that they should be traces of certain operators which are related to arithmetic objects.  Quite possibly, Konsevitch will explain this later in the course.

Comment: Just realised that I have a blog post on this: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/the-riemann-hypothesis-in-various-settings/